# Pretty Url for ONLY .html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, pretty-urls

The other day I tried making my html pages into pretty urls with the [.htaccess] code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This worked for my html pages fine, but when I went to parts of my site that use php (specifically my SMF forum) did not work. Is there anyway I can make this code work for only .html files, and ignore all other php files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check for existence of `.html` file for adding `.html` in a URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```